# Print label of line with regard to line using Java graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jlabel

I am doing a project in which I need to print the label/description of the line (drawn using graphics) with respect to orientation of the line. [image]

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: How are you drawing the lines? could you explain more?

Answer (score 7):

Look to the [`Graphics2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) methods such as [`rotate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#rotate%28double%29), [`scale()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#scale%28double,%20double%29) & [`translate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#translate%28double,%20double%29) - as well as the more general [`translate(AffineTransform)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#transform%28java.awt.geom.AffineTransform%29) method.

See [Transforming Shapes, Text, and Images](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html) in the Java tutorial for more details and working examples, especially of using an [`AffineTransform`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) (which can concatenate scale, rotate, transform **&** shear operations).

---

You do not mention how you obtain the `Graphics` object.  The `Graphics` object passed to Swing components in `paintComponent(Graphics)` will generally be a `Graphics2D` instance, and can be cast to one.  To get a `Graphics2D` instance from a [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), call [`createGraphics()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#createGraphics%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

Make a class called "Labelled line" and make it something like this

```
class LabeledLine {

    private int x1, y1, x2, y2;
    private String label;

    public void drawOn(Graphics g) {
        // need more features? thickness, etc? add it
        g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
        // compute size of text, position of text, angle of text
        // draw that text
    }

}
```

A quick google for drawing angled text gave me a couple results, so that should be easy to do.